# Converting SocketError value to a string message

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

Having a `SocketError` value, how can it be converted to the respective string message?

**Background and Example**:

A failing call to e.g. `Socket.Receive` will throw a `SocketException` with e.g. `Message` “An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host” and `SocketErrorCode == SocketError.ConnectionReset`. However, calling `Socket.ReceiveAsync` will only give a `SocketError == SocketError.ConnectionReset`.

Having this `SocketError.ConnectionReset` (or any other value), how can I get the corresponding message?

Comment: SocketException.ErrorCode is an integer, for example 10053 which means WSAECONNABORTED, which can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx But I don't know of any machine-readable table of codes to texts, or stump of programming.

Comment: I'd peek into the BCL source code to see how they obtain the message. None of the usual socket Win32 functions return a message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done

- using the [`FormatMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function (casting the `SocketError` to an `int`),
- or simpler, by

  ```
  new Win32Exception((int) mySocketError).Message
  ```